# Javascript - Oninput event not working for input number with customizing increment arrows

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

`oninput` event not working with customizing Increment Arrows in javascript or jquery!

```js
$("#myInput").on("input", function (e) {
    console.log("hey");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button onclick="document.getElementById('myInput').stepUp()">+</button>   
<input type="number" id="myInput" value="14">
<button onclick="document.getElementById('myInput').stepDown()">-</button>
```

What should i do?

Comment: I solved -> add ``onClick`` for buttons :/